# how to get PHP variable in HTML form element

Tags: php, html

i have been trying to name a form element to a PHP variable

```
Echo ('<br><br>' . $number1 . ' x ' . $number2 . ' = <input type="text" name="number $i ">' ); // Print out the sums
```

Comment: As `number $i` is in a single quoted string, it will not be evaluated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it the same way you did `$number1` and `$number2`, with string concatenation.

```
Echo ('<br><br>' . $number1 . ' x ' . $number2 . ' = <input type="text" name="number' . $i . '">' ); // Print out the sums
```